# Receive Response over Bluetooth SPP as Client - Tizen .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, tizen, xamarin.tizen

I am trying to receive responses over BT SPP for my client device connected to a server.
After creating the client socket and initiating the bonding
`Client = device.CreateSocket(ServiceUuid);
Client.ConnectionStateChanged += ClientConnectionStateChanged;
device.ConnectionStateChanged += DeviceConnectionStateChanged;
device.CreateBond();`

I call the connect method in the bonding callback `Client.Connect();`, and then subscribe to the OnDataReceived event `Client.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;`

Now everything works but the OnDataReceived is never called, as if there is no data returned. 
But as I am also controlling the server which runs on a secondary device, I know there is data being send back, so why is it not received ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below test code for DataReceived() function.

[https://review.tizen.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=test/tct/csharp/api.git;a=blob;f=tct-suite-vs/Tizen.Bluetooth.Manual.Tests/testcase/TSIBluetoothServerSocket.cs;h=a52a38bb2ce46e384ca24897c27a694173d47fff;hb=refs/heads/tizen][1]

```
303         public async Task DataReceived_CLIENT_EVENT()
304         {
305             try
306             {
307                 /* We can't occupy the precondition, if BT feature is not supported in Manual TC */
308                 if (_isBluetoothSupported == false)
309                 {
310                     BluetoothHelper.DisplayLabel("DataReceived_CLIENT_EVENT");
311                     await ManualTest.WaitForConfirm();
312                     return;
313                 }
314 
315                 BluetoothSetup.CreateClientSocketUtil();
316                 if (BluetoothSetup.Client == null)
317                 {
318                     ManualTest.DisplayCustomLabel("Precondition failed: Test device should be paired to the remote device.");
319                     await ManualTest.WaitForConfirm();
320                     return;
321                 }
322 
323                 await BluetoothSetup.ConnectSocketUtil();
324                 BluetoothSetup.Client.DataReceived += (sender, args) =>
325                 {
326                     Log.Info(Globals.LogTag, "DataReceived in client: "+args.Data.Data);
327                     BluetoothHelper.DisplayPassLabel("DataReceived_SERVER_EVENT");
328                 };
329                 await ManualTest.WaitForConfirm();
```

And, please check one whether the Result is success or not in ConnectionStateChanged callback.